# How to log SQL query in Zend on Zend_Db_Statement_Exception

Tags: zend-framework

When an application error occures on my site and it is connected with malformed SQL query, I'd like to know the query to solve the problem. But it's not easy, when such an error occurs, information is given like this:

> An error occurred
>
> Application error
>
> Exception information:
>
> Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'p.name' in 'where clause'
>
> Stack trace:
>
> ```
> #0 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
> #1 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
> #2 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select), Array)
> #3 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Db/Select.php(686): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
> #4 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Paginator/Adapter/DbSelect.php(142): Zend_Db_Select->query(2)
> #5 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Paginator/Adapter/DbSelect.php(183): Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect->setRowCount(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
> #6 [internal function]: Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect->count()
> #7 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Paginator.php(540): count(Object(Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect))
> #8 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Paginator.php(1081): Zend_Paginator->getTotalItemCount()
> #9 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Paginator.php(753): Zend_Paginator->_calculatePageCount()
> #10 /var/www/ksiegarnia/application/modules/default/controllers/IndexController.php(702): Zend_Paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10)
> #11 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516): IndexController->searchadvancedAction()
> #12 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(308): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('searchadvancedA...')
> #13 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
> #14 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
> #15 /var/www/ksiegarnia/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
> #16 /var/www/ksiegarnia/public_html/index.php(32): Zend_Application->run()
> #17 {main}
> ```

How to log an SQL query that caused the error?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a quite complicated, but useful solution, which is adding the following code to ErrorController.php: 
when the exception is of class Zend_Db_Statement_Exception, go to a specific line of trace, get the Zend_Db_Select argument that was used there and get parts of SQL clause (where, from, order, group etc.) from it and log them into a log file. Nasty, isn't it? ;) But works :)

Here is the code to be inserted into `ErrorController.php`

```
    $thread_id = exec('echo $$');

    if (get_class($errors->exception) == 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception') {
      $trace = $errors->exception->getTrace();

      foreach(array('columns', 'from', 'where', 'order', 'group', 'limitcount', 'limitoffset', 'union') as $queryPartName) {
        $parts = $trace[2]['args'][0]->getPart($queryPartName);
        if ((is_array($parts) && !empty($parts)) ||
            (!is_array($parts) && trim($parts) !== '')) {
          $log->log($thread_id. "\t".strtoupper($queryPartName) .': ', $priority);
          if (is_array($parts)) {
            foreach($parts as $part)
              $log->log($thread_id. "\t"."\t". (is_array($part) ? 'Array: '. implode(', ', $part) : $part), $priority);
          } else
            $log->log($thread_id. "\t"."\t". $parts, $priority);
        }
      }

    }
```